# How can I plot data vs time with matplotlib from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I'm sorry if this a stupid question, but I looked around at different examples and tried them before writing this.

So I have this csv file that I looks as follows

```
 DateTime                        Column_2                   Column_3
 9/1/2019  7:07:46 AM            894                        55
 9/1/2019  7:17:46 AM            895                        58
 9/1/2019  7:27:46 AM            898                        63
```

Now my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data=pd.read_csv('data file.csv')
data=data[data.Column_2 != '(null)']
data[data.Column_3 != '(null)']
data[['Column_2','Column_3']]= [['Column_2','Column_3']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
plt.plot(data.DataTime,data.Column_2)
```

In the above example, I removed some null values in columns 2 and 3, then converted them into int values (they were objects). The DataTime column is an object though, how can I graph the column against the time? Do I change the DataTime to an integer?